# Importing a shared library and the global namespace

Tags: python, shared-libraries

I am trying to import a shared library which contains a number of Python wrappers for a visualisation program ([VisIt](https://wci.llnl.gov/codes/visit/) to be specific). This library is implemented in such a way that one first imports the library, which makes a few functions available, and then you call a function which launches the visualisaion viewer and makes the rest of the API available to call. For example, in the following

```
form visit import *
print dir()
Launch()
print dir()
```

the first print statement contains the usual builtins and a couple of other functions

```
['AddArgument', 'GetDebugLevel', 'Launch', 'SetDebugLevel', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__warningregistry__']
```

and the second print yields

```
['ActivateDatabase', 'AddArgument', 'AddColorTable', 'AddOperator', 'AddPlot', ... ]
```

etc.

I wish to instead call `Launch` within a function (so I can process and pass arguments to `Launch`). However, when I do this the functions which are made available after the call to `Launch` are not in the global namespace, but in the namespace local to the function. So in the following example

```
import sys
from visit import *

def main():

    Launch()
    print dir()
    if "Version" in dir()
        print Version() # This is made available by call to Launch() above

    return 0

if __name__=="__main__":
    ret = main()
    print dir()
    sys.exit(ret)
```

the `print` statement within `main` will print

```
['ActivateDatabase', 'AddArgument', 'AddColorTable', 'AddOperator', 'AddPlot', ... ]
```

as above, whereas the `print` just after `main` is called prints

```
['AddArgument', 'GetDebugLevel', 'Launch', 'SetDebugLevel', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__warningregistry__']
```

as if `Launch` was never called.

My first question is how do I ensure that the global namespace is populated by the call to `Launch`?

Secondly, the call to `Version` actually fails, with the error

> NameError: global name 'Version' is not defined

even though `print "Version" in dir()` returns `True`. Will this problem be resolved if I solve my first problem, or is this something else entirely?

Please let me know if you need more information above the shared library. I don't know a lot about how it is written but I can try and find out.

**Edit:** Following the answer by @voithos the following is the solution I have adopted.

As stated by @voithos, "Visit uses a dynamic import which brings everything to local scope... assuming that you'll never call `visit.Launch()` outside of the global scope." His (initial) answer allows me to make the functions made available by `visit.Launch()` to be used outside (and in) of my main routine, using the prefix `visit.` with all these routines.

To import the VisIt routines as `from visit import *`, so that they may be called without the `visit.` prefix I modify @voithos' use of `setattr` in `main` to the following

```
# Loop through the local namespace and add the names that were just
# imported to the module namespace
loc = locals()
for key in loc:
    setattr(sys.modules[__name__], key, loc[key])
```

then the VisIt routines are available at the module level and all seems well.

Thanks to @voithos for your answer.

Comment: I initially posted my edit as an answer, but feel that it would be better to include it as an update to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Visit uses a dynamic import which brings everything to local scope. Basically, they're assuming that you'll never call `visit.Launch()` outside of the global scope. The launch function is all written in C++, so I'm not sure exactly how it's importing.

One workaround is to reassign the names from the local scope into another scope. (e.g. into the `visit` module that you import) Here's an example:

```
import sys
import visit

def main():
    visit.Launch()

    # Loop through the locals that were just imported
    # and assign the names to the visit module
    loc = locals()
    for key in loc:
        setattr(visit, key, loc[key])

    return 0

if __name__=="__main__":
    ret = main()
    print dir(visit)
    sys.exit(ret)
```

If you'd like to assign the names to the global scope, then you can modify the loop to:

```
loc = locals()
glob = globals()

for key in loc:
    glob[key] = loc[key]
```

A note of caution, however: doing this will overwrite any conflicting symbol names that you had defined before. For example, if you had defined a `Version()` function, the `Version()` from the Visit module will overwrite the older one that you defined. Hence, it's generally a good idea not to clutter the global scope with names unless you really need to.

Comment: Thanks for this answer @voithos - this works well and visit.Version, for example, can now be called successfully both within `main` and after `main` is called. However, can I use a similar work around to add the names local to `main` to the global namespace. This is important if I want to use the same script with VisIt and within a standard Python interpreter.

Comment: @Chris: Sure, that's easy enough. Just assign to the global module instead of to `visit`. You can use `globals()` to access the global symbol table. I've modified the answer to show an example.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used VisIt, but according to their documentation you need to do:

```
import visit

def main():    
    visit.Launch()
```

which will import all the functions into 'visit' namespace. Then you simply interface with the library's function via the visit namespace.  As in:

```
visit.Version()
```

Comment: This gives me the same problem: If I use `import visit` and replace the print statement after `main` is called with `print dir(visit)` then I don't get the full API, only the functions which are initially available before `Launch` is called.

Comment: I should say that there is a reason why I am using `from visit import *` rather than `import visit`. My problem is that the functions made available by `visit.Launch` aren't accessible outside of `main`.